# wp_destroy_current_session() will handle woocommerce session also in the right way?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, security, woocommerce

I have a wordpress + woocommerce installation. I protected the wp-login.php by a .htaccess rule, in order to prevent bruteforce attacks. It's working, however clients logged in cannot log out in the frontend, beacause wordpress uses the wp-login.php for destroying sessions. To solve this problem, I included the following php code in my functions.php within my theme.

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'custom_logout_page', 10, 2 );
function custom_logout_page( $logout_url, $redirect ) {
return 'example.com/custom-log-out-url/';
}
```

I've created a page template for the custom-log-out-url, and in the header section I've included the following php code:

after get_header();

```
wp_destroy_current_session();
```

**My question is:**

the function wp_destory_current_session() will also close woocommerce related session data, I mean, will it handle in the right way, so my site won't end up with messed session data in the woocommerce tables?
Do you consider it the right aproach to protect wp-login.php for preventing automated brutforce attacks?

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1):

Replacing just the URL is not enough. You have to tell WordPress what to do with the new URL.

Sample code, creates a log-out URL like example.com/logout=1 and redirects to front page or custom URL after logging the user out:

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 't5_custom_logout_url', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 't5_custom_logout_action' );

/**
 * Replace default log-out URL.
 *
 * @wp-hook logout_url
 * @param   string $logout_url
 * @param   string $redirect
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_custom_logout_url( $logout_url, $redirect )
{
    $url = add_query_arg( 'logout', 1, home_url( '/' ) );

    if ( ! empty ( $redirect ) )
        $url = add_query_arg( 'redirect', $redirect, $url );

    return $url;
}

/**
 * Log the user out.
 *
 * @wp-hook wp_loaded
 * @return  void
 */
function t5_custom_logout_action()
{
    if ( ! isset ( $_GET['logout'] ) )
        return;

    wp_logout();

    $loc = isset ( $_GET['redirect'] ) ? $_GET['redirect'] : home_url( '/' );
    wp_redirect( $loc );
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Stefano Pascazi!